# Deal with executing Unix command which produces an endless output

Tags: scala, process

Some unix command such as `tail -f` or starting a python web server (i.e. cherrypy) will produce an endless output, i.e. the only way to stop it is to `Ctrl-C`. I'm working on a scala application which execute the command like that, my implemetation is:

```
import scala.sys.process._
def exe(command: String): Unit = {
    command !
}
```

However, as the command produces an endless output stream, the application hangs there until I either terminate it or kill the process started by the command. I also try to add & at the end of the command in order to run it in background but my application still hangs.

Hence, I'm looking for another way to execute a command without hanging my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Seq("sh", "-c", "tail -f /var/log/syslog > /dev/null &") !
```

works for me.  I think Randall's answer fails because scala is just executing the commands, and can't interpret shell operators like "&".  If the command passed to scala is "sh" and the arguments are a complete shell command, we work around this issue.  There also seems to be an issue with how scala parses/separates individual arguments, and using a Seq instead of single String works better for that.

The above is equivalent to the unix command:

```
sh -c 'tail -f /var/log/syslog > /dev/null &'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a custom `ProcessLogger` to deal with output however you wish as soon as it is available.

```
val proc = 
  Process(command).run(ProcessLogger(line => (), err => println("Uh-oh: "+err)))
```

You may kill a process with the `destroy` method.

```
proc.destroy
```

If you are waiting to get a certain output before killing it, you can create a custom `ProcessLogger` that can call `destroy` on its own process once it has what it needs.

You may prefer to use `lines` (in 2.10; the name is changing to `lineStream` in 2.11) instead of `run` to gather standard output, since that will give you a stream that will block when no new output is available.  Then you wrap the whole thing in a `Future`, read lines from the stream until you have what you need, and then kill the process--this simplifies blocking/waiting.

Comment: Hi. What I want is to continue while neither destroying a process nor being blocked. In other words, I want to start a process (i.e. execute a command), let it run and then move on to do another thing regardless the output of the process is.

Answer (score 0):

If you close the descriptor(s) from which you're reading the process' output, it will get a `SIGPIPE` and (usually) terminate.

If you just don't want the output, redirect to `/dev/null`:

```
command arg arg arg >/dev/null 2>&1
```

**Addendum:** This pertains only to Unix-alike systems, not Windows.

Comment: I don't understand about closing the descriptor(s) means. However, I tried your second solution but it doesn't work...

Comment: When you use the process utilities to execute a host OS command, you always end up with three file descriptors, one writable that supplies the process' standard input and two readable descriptors that convey the process' standard output and standard error to your JVM process.

Comment: how to disable output for Windows?